# Looking to bulk assign posts in category a to category b

Tags: wordpress

I am in need of some help. I have been working on this a lot. I have several categories in my Wordpress installation.  I am looking to add a new category to many posts at one time (around 4000 posts). So posts who are in category a, b, c and d  should also be added to a new category e, but they should remain in the category they are in now as well.

What is the best solution for this?  This is bulk, so the standard WP features takes too much time.

Comment: What do you mean?  Doing it via WP-admin?  it will not work with around 400 posts at a time

Comment: no, i mean have you tried insert using php code and wp functions to insert data , Like `wp_insert_post($args);`

Comment: hmm. no. How would it do that?

Comment: Look https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: is there other ways to do it. or, is there a way to add a additional category to ALL posts?

Comment: you would to check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

Comment: <?php

// An array of IDs of categories we to add to this post.
$cat_ids = array( 6, 8 );

/*
 * If this was coming from the database or another source, we would need to make sure
 * these were integers:

$cat_ids = array_map( 'intval', $cat_ids );
$cat_ids = array_unique( $cat_ids );

 */

// Add these categories, note the last argument is true.
$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( 42, $cat_ids, 'category', true );

if ( is_wp_error( $term_taxonomy_ids ) ) {
 // There was an error somewhere and the terms couldn't be set.
} else {
 // Success! These categories were added to the post.
}

Comment: Maybe I can use the one Adding Categories to a Post on the link you wrote. But how do I change it, so that e.g. it updates a lot of posts, instead of just post with id 42 as it seems in that example?  Is it possible to e.g. add that you want cat:id 3 added to all posts with id between 1 and 8000 ?  How would you do that?   Could it cause  a server timeout?